# When i choose a value from a dropdown list to solve a value in the grid but it overwrites it

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I need help subtracting the `MonthlySalary` with Tardy, halfdaypenalty and earlyout but add overtime reward

Example of the table

```
CREATE TABLE PAYROLL
(
    RegEmpID INT,
    PayID INT IDENTITY (100, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    TardyPenalty DECIMAL,
    HalfdayPenalty DECIMAL,
    EarlyOutPenalty DECIMAL,
    MonthlySalary DECIMAL,
    OvertimeReward DECIMAL
)
```

I can't seem to find a way to solve them individually and or altogether

So basically it's this there is a dropdown list in asp.net that each of these has a value specifically late = 50 halfday =50 earlyout = 50. The salary already has a set value and each time i tried to it seems to overwrite the total value with theirs.

Here's the code

```
protected void btnupdatepay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double total;
    double tardy;
    double half;
    double early;
    double payroll;
    double overtime;

    total = 0;
    tardy = 0.0;
    half = 0.0;
    early = 0.0;
    payroll = 0.0;
    overtime = 0.0;

    if (Penalty.SelectedValue == "Tardy")
    {
        tardy = 50;
        total = total - tardy;
    }

    if (Penalty.SelectedValue == "Half Day")
    {
        half = 100;
        total = total - half;
    }

    if (Penalty.SelectedValue == "Early Out")
    {
        early = 50;
        total = total - early;
    }

    if (Penalty.SelectedValue == "Overtime")
    {
        overtime = 100;
        total = total + overtime;
    }

    total = total + overtime - half - early - tardy;

    int rowsAffected;

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connect"].ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE PAYROLL SET [TardyPenalty] = @TardyPenalty, [HalfdayPenalty] = @HalfdayPenalty, [EarlyOutPenalty] = @EarlyOutPenalty , [OvertimeReward] = @OvertimeReward, [MonthlySalary]= @MonthlySalary WHERE [PayID] = @PayID", con);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TardyPenalty", tardy);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HalfdayPenalty", half);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EarlyOutPenalty", early);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PayID", txtpayid.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OvertimeReward", overtime);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MonthlySalary", total);

    try
    {
        con.Open();
        rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        datapay.DataBind();
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Maybe I'm doing something wrong - can't find a way

Comment: So what's the issue you are facing with this code ?

Comment: i dont know if the query is correct because i needed the grid to display each and every value that i choose from the dropdown list but when i choose one for example 3 of them have the value 50 but if i choose one while the one was already inputted it overwrites it and the value of the other one turns to 0

Comment: **(1)** if you use `DECIMAL` in your table, that is equivalent to `DECIMAL(18,0)` - a decimal value with **no digits** after the decimal point - is that really what you need?? Otherwise, explicitly define how many digits before and after the decimal point you need! **(2)** Don't use `double` datatype in C# - it's notoriously imprecise and prone to rounding error - use `decimal` instead, *especially* when dealing with monetary values

Comment: Do i need to give them the value? because the value is inserted in the IF statements as presented above.. when it is chosen from the list.. still having a hard time dealing with the sql statement though perhaps using SELECT and SUM would be correct here?

Comment: I mean it still doesnt calculate as written in the code so im stuck..

Answer (score 0):

Seems your "total" variable should have a different name in your handler. Try to use, for example, _total:

```
double _total = 0;

//work with _total

total = _total + ...
```

Comment: can you please explain a bit more?

Comment: Their could be an issue with initial values. Did you try to breakpoint the cmd initialization lines?

Comment: i tried using insert but to no avail. Update seems to be wrong

Comment: Well, your PayID should be **int** but you set _text_ value to parameter. Check it, please.

Comment: oh thats for the select option because every id updates without it . i placed it there so it specifies which ID should be updated without it every ID is updated

Comment: try to use `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PayID", Convert.ToInt32(txtpayid.Text));`

Comment: @AlexLunyov No, don't use the problem-prone [addwithvalue](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).

Answer (score 0):

You are starting with local variable total as 0

total = 0

Now you are doing calculation on this 0. Put this as a Global variable and use different name from local variable

Comment: the value of total = monthlysalary is inserted from a different tab so it shows the value inserted as e.g 8000 from a different gridview but when i use the drop down list to add Late for example it is supposed to subtract 50 from 8k  but the problem is that it overwrites it and turns the monthly salary into 50 aswell